# How to right align an equation?

Tags: align

I have an equation and i want to right align it:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,bm} %math

%----------------------------------------
%Align Equations to LEFT MARGIN (use \mathleft then \mathcenter)
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathleft}{\@fleqntrue\@mathmargin0pt}
\newcommand{\mathcenter}{\@fleqnfalse}
\makeatother
%----------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
center
\end{align}
\mathleft
\begin{align}
left
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I have an awesome piece of code that allows me to leftalign with `\mathleft`, is it possible to have one that right align?

[image]

Comment: What should this alternation mean? Is it just for academic curiosity?

Comment: @egreg I really got something in which thing was right next to the equation number, but now I'm on a different machine and can't reproduce it. I'll therefore remove my comments.

Comment: @egreg I'm back home at my machine, and posted an illustration [below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/428594/121799). Either my TeXLive is broken, I am drunk, or I have a point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Of course you can, though not without reading the TeXbook (Exercise 19.8). Look at the final example, though, which could be what you're looking for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation}
\hfilneg \text{left} \hspace{10000pt minus 1fil}
\end{equation}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation}
\text{center}
\end{equation}
\lipsum*[4]
\begin{equation}
\hspace{10000pt minus 1fil} \text{right} \hfilneg
\end{equation}
But I guess you want something like this final example,
because ``right aligning'' equations has generally no
use:
\begin{multline}
\text{the first part of a very long equation,
      that is set flush left} \\
\text{the final part, also quite long, set flush right}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was thinking about separating the equation in 2 environments, however, as you predicted, multiline did the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can right justify an equation using flalign

```
 \begin{flalign}
   && E^2 = (mC^2)^2 + (pC)^2
 \end{flalign}
```