# filling with spaces from the left

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

How do I make the formula in the new line starting with `$\y_i\geq x_i$`
appear at the very r.h.s. margin of the paper without using repeatedly
`\quad`
i.e. filling with blanks from the left ?

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a  [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing how you recieved the above output?

Comment: Probably https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/428419/134144 is helpful.

Comment: most likely you should use the `multline` environment which will set the last line flush right, but as you have provided no test document, I'm not going to type in that entire equation for an answer.