# Chemical equation does not fit

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

Is there any possibility to get my chemical equation on the same line of the page?
The water should be on the right side of the equation.
It would also look nicer with the structural formula "isoniazid" on the same level as the reaction arrow, because it is a bit higher than I expected it to be.

Thank you very much!

EDIT:

The water should be on the right side of the equation.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\section{Chemical equation}

\ce{\chemfig{N*6(=-=(-(=[2]O)-[-0.5]\chemabove{N}{H}-[0.5]NH_2)-=-)} + HNO2 ->
\chemfig{N*6(=-=(-(=[2]O)-[-0.5]\chemabove{N}{\scriptstyle-}-
\chemabove{N}{\scriptstyle+}~N)-=-)} + 2H2O}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same goes the structural formula of "clotrimazole", it does not fit in the line of the page and is not on the same level as the reaction arrow.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\section{Chemical equation}

\ce{CH3COOH2+
+ \chemfig{*6(-=(-Cl)-(-(-[1]N*5(-=-N=-))(-[3]*6(-=-=-=))-[-0.65]*6(=-=-=-))=-=-)}
<=> CH3COOH
+ \chemfig{*6(-=(-Cl)-(-(-[1]N*5(-=-\chemabove{N}{\chemabove{H}{\scriptstyle+}}=-))
(-[3]*6(-=-=-=))-[-0.65]*6(=-=-=-))=-=-)}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT 2:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\section{Chemical equation}

\schemestart
\chemfig{HClO_4}
\arrow(--[yshift=0pt,xshift=-1.5cm]){0}
\+
\chemfig{CH_3COOH}
\arrow(mid.east--mid.west){->}
\chemfig{CH_3COO\charge{45:1.5pt=$\scriptstyle+$}{H}_2}
\arrow(--[yshift=0pt,xshift=-1.5cm]){0}
\+
\chemfig{Cl\charge{45:1.5pt=$\scriptstyle-$}{O_4}}
\schemestop

\bigskip

\schemestart
\chemfig{CH_3COOH}
\arrow(--[yshift=0pt,xshift=-1.5cm]){0}
\+
\chemfig{CH_3COOH}
\arrow(mid.east--mid.west){->}
\chemfig{CH_3COO\charge{45:1.5pt=$\scriptstyle+$}{H}_2}
\arrow(--[yshift=0pt,xshift=-1.5cm]){0}
\+
\chemfig{CH_3CO\charge{45:1.5pt=$\scriptstyle-$}{O}}
\schemestop

\bigskip

\scalebox{0.7}{
\schemestart
\chemfig{*6(-=(-Cl)-(-(-[1]N*5(-=-N=-))(-[3]*6(-=-=-=))-[-0.65]*6(=-=-=-))=-=-)}
\arrow(--[yshift=0pt,xshift=-1.5cm]){0}
\+
\chemfig{CH_3COO\charge{45:1.5pt=$\scriptstyle+$}{H}_2}
\arrow(mid.east--mid.west){->}
\chemfig{*6(-=(-Cl)-(-(-[1]N*5(-=-\chemabove{N}{\chemabove{H}{\scriptstyle+}}=-))(-[3]*6(-=-=-=))-[-0.65]*6(=-=-=-))=-=-)}
\arrow(--[yshift=0pt,xshift=-1.5cm]){0}
\+
\chemfig{CH_3COOH}
\schemestop
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please prepare a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that others can use in order to reproduce the output you get. What exactly does "on the same level as the reaction arrow" mean in this context? Do you want to vertically center the structure with respect to the arrow or do you prefer a different alignment? If so, which?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Please look at my edit...

Comment: The structural formula of "isoniazid" is a bit higher than I expected it to be. I want it to be more tidy. It should be on the same level as the reaction arrow and the formula "nitrous acid". The same for the product and water.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure how it should look like in the end. Here is a guess:

**EDIT1:** I adjusted the equations manualy with `\arrow(--[yshift=<value>,xshift=<value>]){0}`

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    
\setchemfig{scheme debug=true}
    \scalebox{.6}{
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{N*6(=-=(-(=[2]O)-[-0.5]\chemabove{N}{H}-[0.5]NH_2)-=-)} 
    \arrow(--[yshift=-20pt,xshift=-50pt]){0}
        \+ 
        \chemfig{HNO_2} 
        \arrow(--[yshift=20pt]){->}
        \chemfig{N*6(=-=(-(=[2]O)-[-0.5]\chemabove{N}{\scriptstyle-}-
            \chemabove{N}{\scriptstyle+}~N)-=-)} 
        \arrow(--[yshift=-20pt,xshift=-50pt]){0}
        \+ 
        \chemfig[yshift=1000cm]{H_2O}
    \schemestop
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Before:**

[image]

and the other:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\section{Chemical equation}

%\setchemfig{scheme debug=true}
\scalebox{.6}{
\schemestart
\chemfig{*6(-=(-Cl)-(-(-[1]N*5(-=-N=-))(-[3]*6(-=-=-=))-[-0.65]*6(=-=-=-))=-=-)}
\arrow(--[yshift=0pt,xshift=-1.5cm]){0}
\+
\chemfig{CH_3COO\charge{45:1.5pt=$\scriptstyle+$}{H}_2}
\arrow(mid.east--mid.west){->}
\chemfig{*6(-=(-Cl)-(-(-[1]N*5(-=-\chemabove{N}{\chemabove{H}{\scriptstyle+}}=-))(-[3]*6(-=-=-=))-[-0.65]*6(=-=-=-))=-=-)}
\arrow(--[yshift=0pt,xshift=-1.5cm]){0}
\+
\chemfig{CH_3COOH}
\schemestop
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Before:**

[image]

**EDIT2:** Aligning of equations:You can use `\equations*` from `\amsmath` package and left align them with this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/428419/224762) of @egreg.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    
    \section{Chemical equation}
    \begin{equation*}
    \hfilneg
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{HClO_4}
    \arrow(--[yshift=0pt,xshift=-1.5cm]){0}
    \+
    \chemfig{CH_3COOH}
    \arrow(mid.east--mid.west){->}
    \chemfig{CH_3COO\charge{45:1.5pt=$\scriptstyle+$}{H}_2}
    \arrow(--[yshift=0pt,xshift=-1.5cm]){0}
    \+
    \chemfig{Cl\charge{45:1.5pt=$\scriptstyle-$}{O_4}}
    \schemestop 
    \hspace{10000pt minus 1fil}
\end{equation*}
    \bigskip
    \begin{equation*}
    \hfilneg
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{CH_3COOH}
    \arrow(--[yshift=0pt,xshift=-1.5cm]){0}
    \+
    \chemfig{CH_3COOH}
    \arrow(mid.east--mid.west){->}
    \chemfig{CH_3COO\charge{45:1.5pt=$\scriptstyle+$}{H}_2}
    \arrow(--[yshift=0pt,xshift=-1.5cm]){0}
    \+
    \chemfig{CH_3CO\charge{45:1.5pt=$\scriptstyle-$}{O}}
    \schemestop
    \hspace{10000pt minus 1fil}
    \end{equation*}
    \bigskip
    \begin{equation*}
    \hfilneg
    \scalebox{0.7}{
        \schemestart
        \chemfig{*6(-=(-Cl)-(-(-[1]N*5(-=-N=-))(-[3]*6(-=-=-=))-[-0.65]*6(=-=-=-))=-=-)}
        \arrow(--[yshift=0pt,xshift=-1.5cm]){0}
        \+
        \chemfig{CH_3COO\charge{45:1.5pt=$\scriptstyle+$}{H}_2}
        \arrow(mid.east--mid.west){->}
        \chemfig{*6(-=(-Cl)-(-(-[1]N*5(-=-\chemabove{N}{\chemabove{H}{\scriptstyle+}}=-))(-[3]*6(-=-=-=))-[-0.65]*6(=-=-=-))=-=-)}
        \arrow(--[yshift=0pt,xshift=-1.5cm]){0}
        \+
        \chemfig{CH_3COOH}
        \schemestop
        }
    \hspace{10000pt minus 1fil}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Roland!
Apparently it does not work with the second chemical equation below...

Is it possible to use the reaction arrow in \ce{->}? I really do not like the \arrow.
The formula of "nitrous acid" an "water" should be higher (on the same level as the arrow).

Comment: Thanks @Roland!
However, I do have more equations in my pdf, which now have a different size.
Do you have any suggestions?
Please look at my answer below to check the code.

Comment: The formula of "acetic acid" is way more smaller compared to the other equation. The last two equations also moved to the right compared to the first equation (just look at the methyl group).

Comment: The reason the acetic acid is smaller is simlpe because I scaled down the whole equation with `scalebox` to fit it on one page. Remove ` \scalebox{.6}{  }` and the equation will have the normal size but it will no longer fit on one A4 page.

Comment: You can manually shift the molecules with `xshift=<value>` see edit.

Comment: Thank you very much, Roland.  What I said may have been unclear: The first equation is more on left side of the page, the second and third equation are more on the right side of the page. I will show you a pic of it in my question.

Comment: Thank you @Roland you are the best!

Answer (score 1):

Use only the "chemfig" command if possible. The molecules can only be fine-tuned within the "chemfig" environment, use \schemestart and \schemestop

Invisible arrows will adjust position.

```
\schemestart
%
\chemfig{[,1.5]N*6(=-=(-(=[2]O)-[-0.5]\chemabove{N}{H}-[0.5]NH_2)-=-)}
\arrow{0}[0,.1]\+ 
\chemfig{HNO_2}
%
\arrow{->}
%
\chemfig{[,1.5]N*6(=-=(-(=[2]O)-[-0.5]\chemabove{N}{\scriptstyle-}-\chemabove{N}{\scriptstyle+}~N)-=-)}
\arrow{0}[0,.1]\+ 
2 \chemfig{H_2O}
%
\schemestop
```

[image]